# React Error with marketplace application checkout page

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Right now I am learning how to code in React. I am working on an Amazon clone and it is coming along, I have been able to solve every issue that I ran into (mostly because they were relatively trivial) but this latest problem really has me blocked and while I keep at finding a fix I figured why not make a Stack Overflow account and ask here as well.

Here is the error:

```html
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {value}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
▶ 17 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
src/index.js:9
   6 | import reducer, { initialState } from "./reducer";
   7 | import { StateProvider } from "./StateProvider";
   8 | 
>  9 | ReactDOM.render(
  10 |   <React.StrictMode>
  11 |     <StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
  12 |       <App />
View compiled
./src/index.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:2644:34
__webpack_require__
/Users/code/marketplace-app/webpack/bootstrap:851
  848 | 
  849 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  850 | try {
> 851 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  852 | } finally {
  853 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  854 | }
View compiled
fn
/Users/code/marketplace-app/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:2977:37
__webpack_require__
/Users/code/marketplace-app/webpack/bootstrap:851
  848 | 
  849 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  850 | try {
> 851 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  852 | } finally {
  853 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  854 | }
View compiled
checkDeferredModules
/Users/code/marketplace-app/webpack/bootstrap:45
  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | 
View compiled
webpackJsonpCallback
/Users/code/marketplace-app/webpack/bootstrap:32
  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;
View compiled
global code
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:87
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
```

Here is the Checkout.js file that I think the code is coming from:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./Checkout.css";
import Subtotal from "./Subtotal";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";
import CheckoutProduct from "./CheckoutProduct";

function Checkout() {
  const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  return (
    <div className="checkout">
      <div className="checkout__left">
        <img
          className="checkout__ad"
          src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/02/UK_CCMP/TM/OCC_Amazon1._CB423492668_.jpg"
          alt=""
        />

        <div>
          <h3>Hello, {user?.email}</h3>
          <h2 className="checkout__title">Your shopping Basket</h2>

          {basket.map(item => (
            <CheckoutProduct
              id={item.id}
              title={item.title}
              image={item.image}
              price={item.price}
              rating={item.rating}
            />
          ))};

        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="checkout__right">
        <Subtotal />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Checkout;
```

Here is the index.js file:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import reducer, { initialState } from "./reducer";
import { StateProvider } from "./StateProvider";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
      <App />
    </StateProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Subtotal.js file:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./Subtotal.css";
import CurrencyFormat from "react-currency-format";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";
import { getBasketTotal } from "./reducer";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function Subtotal() {
    const history = useHistory();
    const [{basket},dispatch] = useStateValue();
    
    return (
        <div className="subtotal">
            <CurrencyFormat
              renderText={(value) => (
                  <>
                    <p>
                        Subtotal ({basket.length} items):
                        <strong>{{value}}</strong>
                    </p>
                    <small className="subtotal__gift">
                        <input type="checkbox" /> This order contains a gift 
                    </small>
                  </>
              )}
              decimalScale={2}
              value={getBasketTotal(basket)}
              displayType={"text"}
              thousandSeparator={true}
              prefix={"$"}
            />

            <button onClick={e => history.push('/payment')}>Proceed to Checkout</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Subtotal
```

I created the folder using the npx create-react-app template command and I cannot find a solution. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That error in React is a common one and it is exactly as it says. It doesn't allow you to render objects themselves onto the DOM. It will error because it won't know what to do with them. You have to target the specific keys inside each object and render those instead. I'd start there as that is likely the root of your problem.